# OP requesting his/her post to be deleted

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

Going through the Reopen Review queue, and came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846713/combine-two-variables-crawling-output), which has been edited to this:

> It is a duplicate. Accidentally created two questions

I assume OP (who may not be experienced with SO) wants to remove this question, but apart from leaving it closed, I don't know what I should do next. I can:

1. 'Undo' the previous commit and leave it as a duplicate
2. Post a comment to tell OP to delete the question
3. Flag to report it as "in need of moderator intervention"
4. Do nothing

Comment: User has a delete button. If the user wishes to delete, that would be the appropriate choice.

Answer (score 16):

OP says that he "Accidentally created two questions". There's absolutely no reason why to keep this question alive, it definitely should be deleted so I wouldn't rollback to previous commit.

I also wouldn't "do nothing" because the question *should* be deleted, this leaves you with options 2 and 3. I would begin with 2 and verify he notice the "delete" button, if he doesn't respond for a while, I would flag it.

Comment: I've added a comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846713/combine-two-variables-crawling-output#comment55545174_33846713). The problem with 2) is that I might just forget about it afterwards. So if the question is not deleted by OP, it'll just sit there, so I didn't know whether to flag it straight away.

Comment: @dayuloli You can flag it, I don't see anything wrong with that. But I prefer to make him aware of the "delete" button in the future.